# how to get date and tilte onclick title in full calender

Tags: javascript, java, jquery, fullcalendar

How to get date and title on onclick title event in full calender.
following code is to display calender.

```
$(document).ready(function() { 
     var calendar =  $('#calendar').fullCalendar({
        header: {
            left: 'title',
            center: 'agendaDay,agendaWeek,month',
            right: 'prev,next today'
        },
       //other full calender code.
});
```

I have used following function to add data dynamically on full calender.

```
$(document).ready(function() {          

        var json = JSON.parse(getCalenderEventList());

        for (var i = 0; i < json.length; i++) {
            var a = json[i].title;
            var b = json[i].start;

            $('#calendar').fullCalendar('renderEvent', {
                title: a,
                start: b
            });
        }
    });
```

Everything is working great. Now when I click on the title in full calender, I want to called a function. like..

```
function showDateAndTitle(date, title){
    alert(date);
    alert(title);
}
```

How should be done this? Can anyone help on this?
Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to add the callback `eventClick` to the `fullCalendar` object like this:

```
$(document).ready(function() { 
     var calendar =  $('#calendar').fullCalendar({
        header: {
            left: 'title',
            center: 'agendaDay,agendaWeek,month',
            right: 'prev,next today'
        },
        eventClick: function(event, jsEvent, view) {
          alert('Event: ' + event.title);
          alert('start date event: ' + event.start._i); 
        }
});
```

ref: [eventClick](https://fullcalendar.io/docs/eventClick)

Comment: `@zb22` It works for me. Thank you very much for your help.